# Android Show/Hide Custom Buttons in Mediaplayer

Tags: android, button, media-player, hide

I have been searching on how to show/hide the buttons I have created for this mediaPlayer but cannot find good examples...I would like the controls to disappear and reappear on screen taps like mediaController does. Very new to Java and Android, the player and controls are working as expected but now I need to hide/show them on screen tap. thanks for any help (Xml is below the Java code)

```
    public class Audio_Image extends BT_activity_base implements
      MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
      MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener {

     private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
     private MediaPlayer mp = null;
     private boolean mShowing = false;

     private Button play;
     private Button pause;
     private Button stop;

     private String dataURL = "";
     public String thisActivityName = "Audio_Image";

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            //reference to base layout..
           LinearLayout baseView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.baseView);

           //setup background colors...
           BT_viewUtilities.updateBackgroundColorsForScreen(this, this.screenData);

           //setup background images..
           if(backgroundImageWorkerThread == null){
               backgroundImageWorkerThread = new BackgroundImageWorkerThread();
               backgroundImageWorkerThread.start();
           }            

           //setup navigation bar...
           LinearLayout navBar = BT_viewUtilities.getNavBarForScreen(this, this.screenData);
           if(navBar != null){
               baseView.addView(navBar);
           }

           //inflate this screens layout file...
           LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)thisActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           View thisScreensView = vi.inflate(R.layout.audio_image, null);

           //add the view to the base view...
           baseView.addView(thisScreensView);

         //fill JSON properties...
                dataURL = BT_strings.getJsonPropertyValue(this.screenData.getJsonObject(), "dataURL", "");




      play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
      pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
      stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

      play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
        play();



       }
      });

      pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) { 

           pause();

       }
      });

      stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
        stop();
       }
      });
     }

     private void play() {
         showProgress("Starting audio stream...", 
                 "Please be patient. If you're on 3G this could take a bit.\nWi-Fi is much better for streaming.");

      Uri myUri = Uri.parse(dataURL);
      try {
       if (mp == null) {
        this.mp = new MediaPlayer();
       } else {
        mp.stop();
        mp.reset();
       }
       mp.setDataSource(this, myUri); // Go to Initialized state
       mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
       mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
       mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);

       mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
       mp.prepareAsync();

       Log.d(TAG, "LoadClip Done");
      } catch (Throwable t) {
       Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
      }
     }

     @Override
     public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) { 
      Log.d(TAG, "Stream is prepared");
      mp.start();
      mp.setLooping(true);
      hideProgress();
     }

     private void pause() {
         if(mp!=null) 
         if (mp.isPlaying()) { pause.setText("Pause/Resume");
             mp.pause();
          } else { 
              mp.start();
          }

     }



     private void stop() {
         if(mp!=null) mp.stop();

     }

     @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      stop();

     }

     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
         stop();

     }

     public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append("Media Player Error: ");
      switch (what) {
      case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
       sb.append("Not Valid for Progressive Playback");
       break;
      case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
       sb.append("Server Died");
       break;
      case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
       sb.append("Unknown");
       break;
      default:
       sb.append(" Non standard (");
       sb.append(what);
       sb.append(")");
      }
      sb.append(" (" + what + ") ");
      sb.append(extra);
      Log.e(TAG, sb.toString());
      return true;
     }

     public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
      Log.d(TAG, "PlayerService onBufferingUpdate : " + percent + "%");
     }

        }
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <Button
  android:text="Play"
  android:id="@+id/play"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="20sp">

 </Button>
 <Button
  android:text="Pause"
  android:id="@+id/pause"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="20sp"></Button>
 <Button
  android:text="Stop"
  android:id="@+id/stop"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="20sp"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You juste have to set a click listener on your layout, and 1/2 time you setvisibility to true or false ...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I will custom `media player` by maked it a sub class of `LinearLayout`. In this way I can reuse it, and make show/hide by `setVisiblity()` here are example

```
public Player(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.player, this, true);
    progressText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerProcessText);
    progressControl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.playerSeekbar);
    btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playerPlay);
    btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playerStop);
    btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playerClose);
    initListener();
}

public void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}

private void initListener() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isStop && !isPlay && !isPaused) {
                release();
                setPlayer();
                isStop = false;
                btnPlay.setText("PlayAfterStop");
                onEverySecond.run();
            }
            if (!isPaused) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                btnPlay.setText("PauseWhilePlay");
                isPaused = true;

            } else if (isPlay) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                btnPlay.setText("StartAfterPause");
                isPaused = false;
                isPlay = true;
                onEverySecond.run();
            }
        }
    });

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setStop();

        }
    });

    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setStop();
            Player.this.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    })
```

.....................

[image]

Comment: so you are showing and hiding the whole view? this with a button tap or full view tapped to toggle controls?